# Snippet body is partially clipped/obscured in the snippet editor

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets

Stack Snippets on SO apparently got some CSS changes (at least), which unfortunately cause part of the snippet body to be clipped/obscured in the snippet editor, at least on Chrome (v51.0.2704.79 on Linux):

[image]

In the image above the top and left of the input box are clipped off. Replicated it after clearing cache (just in case).

I've used a smallish window for that picture, but the size of the window doesn't seem to matter.

Same thing happens here on MSE, although sometimes it's only the left side not the top.

Test snippet:

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: I can't repro this bug, which browser and OS are you using?

Comment: "Starting just a few minutes ago" - the update has happened hours ago...

Comment: I can't repro either.

Comment: I can repro on chrome/win10 @nicael

Comment: @nicael: Caching maybe? Definitely wasn't happening for me even two hours ago. In any case, that's not what's important.

Comment: @Stéphane: Linux for me, rene says Windows 10 as well.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326043

Comment: @T.J.Crowder SS got screwed up royally... A lot of bugs being posted on MSO. Check.

Comment: @PraveenKumar: That's only related in that it relates to snippets. It's nothing to do with this update as far as I know, just someone misusing snippets and then indenting them, removing the blank line before the ending snippet comment, etc.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Okie dokie.

Comment: *"The problem described here can no longer be reproduced."* Right, because it was **fixed**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed now, probably by the same update that fixed [this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326042/157247) with padding.